# Convert string CSV to a Char CSV C#

Tags: c#, string, csv, char

I have a `string` `CSV` which has values `"1,2"`.

I need to convert it to a `Char` `CSV` to be passed to a stored procedure. Which looks like. `"'1','2'"`.

I tried something like following. But its not working.

```
String.Join(",", equipmentName.ToArray<char>())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
var result = string.Join(",", "1,2".Split(',').Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x)));
```

**Output**

```
 '1','2'
```

Comment: Be careful that your input doesn't have any escaped sequences when doing this.

Comment: @CoryNelson That's true, I'll edit and add  a note to let OP handle this case.